# Conditional rendering in aura not working

Tags: lightning, aura

I am trying to disable lightning:button based on picklist field values, and the button needs to blurred out or Disabled for 4 picklist values, and i am writing lightning:button tag as mentioned below:

<lightning:button label="LABEL" onclick="{!c.dosomething}"
disabled="{!or(item.fieldapi == 'value 1', item.fieldapi == 'value 2', item.fieldapi ==
'value 3'. item.fieldapi == 'value 4')}"/>

Above works only for value 1 and value 2, but not for value 3 and value 4
if i change the order then again first 2 will work and gets disabled.

It will be a Great help for any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `or()` function [only accepts two arguments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm).

> This function supports only two arguments. Any arguments after the first two are ignored.

You'll want to use the `||` operator instead:

> `||` 
> If you have more than two arguments, you can chain multiple || operations.

Comment: Its working for || operator.Thank you